# submitting form with jquery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code, as simple as it gets:

```
<form action="">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

```js
$("form").submit(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  e.submit(); // tried also: $(this).submit()
});
```

What am I doing wrong here? why doesn't it send?

Comment: Because you've set `preventDefault()`.... What exactly are you trying to do here as the code in your question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: `$("form").submit()`, already submits the form

Comment: why catch the event when you just submit it again without modifying anything?

Comment: it was an EXAMPLE, folks... come on... I will have an if-else statement there.

Comment: "it was an EXAMPLE", then label it as such. This code makes no sense practically, hence the responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
e.target.submit();
```

If you call the submit on the native element, rather than the jQuery element, the jQuery event handlers will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

remove `preventDefault`, it will prevent form submission.

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    //e.preventDefault();
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `.submit()` method on the form directly:

```
$("form").submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

The way your code is written now you are handling the submit event of the form and trying to submit it.  If you inspected e you would see that it is an event and not the actual form.  Your form is submitting just by clicking the submit button.  If you wanted to prevent that and do something before submitting it, do something like this:

```
<form action="" id="myForm">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="button" value="submit" id="myButton">
</form>

$("#myButton").click(function(){
  $(this).stopPropagation();
  $(this).preventDefault();

  //do what you need to do 

  $("#myForm").submit();
});
```

In your original code if you do actually submit the form at the end it will result in an infinite loop.